# Please correct a misleading comment on a question

Tags: support

I'm referring to this question : [Arduino LED brightness switching using pushbutton](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/66523/arduino-led-brightness-switching-using-pushbutton) and more specifically to the comments made to it by [yahya-tawil](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/8698/yahya-tawil).

These comments are incorrect in that they state that when using the Arduino library the `analogWrite` function can only be used with the "analog" pins A0..A5 (Arduino-style numbering). In fact, although this may be misleading, `analogRead` and `analogWrite` aren't "symmetrical" functions, the former is used to read adc values (pins A0..A5) and the last is used to vary the duty cycle of PWM outputs (pins D3, D5, D6, D9, D10, D11).

Can someone please correct these comments for the sake of posterity ?

As a side note, please feel free to tell me if this meta site isn't the right place to ask this. I searched for some time another way to do this but didn't found any ; seems I can't comment myself because of reputation system and I couldn't find a way to send a direct message to the user. I also tried the chat room but reputation was in my way once again :)

Comment: OK, just call me stupid. I just noticed there was a "show 1 more comment" link at the end of the comments list, and this comment just exactly addresses the problem I just mentionned :( The last part of my question still holds, though.

Answer (score 5):

The correct way to express disagreement with a comment is to say so in another comment, or even better, write a correct (as you see it) answer.  Comments aren't peer-reviewed like answers are, so people shouldn't be using them as substitutes for answers anyway.  Incorrect comments happen.  However, also consider that you (or someone else in a different situation) may be wrong about a comment being incorrect.  Why should your judgement that a comment is incorrect have more weight than the judgement of the person that wrote the comment you disagree with?

This is why we have a voting system on answers.  If you really have something useful to add, write a answer.  If you think someone else's answer is right or wrong, upvote or downvote accordingly.  The system unfortunately doesn't require it, but if you do downvote a answer due to technical inaccuracy (as you see it), you really should leave a comment.  That allows the author to fix the mistake if he agrees or rebut if he doesn't.

Comment: I'm sorry but I think you've totally misunderstood my query. 

I've never asked for my judgment to be given more weight than anyone else : I saw a false statement (my opinion, ok) that I had no _technical_ way to contradict (no comment, no downvoting, no flags, ...) and so I imagined I could report it here so that someone who would agree with me could correct it. 

I understand now that I've made at least 2 errors (especially thanks to @anindo-ghosh answer) : 1/ the comment was already corrected but I didn't saw it. 2/ I gave to comments an importance that they don't deserve apparently.

Comment: You have no way to comment only because you are using an account which was brand new and has not yet earned even a minimal level of trust (reputation) from activity anywhere in the stack exchange system.

Answer (score 0):

A key point is that you will have more ability to respond, such as in your own comment, once you develop a very minimal amount of reputation on the site.

This isn't perfect, but is part of the spam and noise filtering methods.

And while imperfect, the threshold to comment is quite low - in fact it's only half of the starting reputation you'd obtain if you linked your profile to an established one you had on any of the other stack exchange sites.

Answer (score -1):

A thought:

Perhaps in similar situations, you could flag the comment with "Other", mentioning why you feel the comment is factually incorrect. That'll bring it to the attention of moderators, and if the matter is serious enough I'm sure it will be dealth with.

However, factual errors in comments do happen - It's not like answers, where the community can vote down to express disagreement.

While there may be merit to raising a [feature-request](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) for a downvote method for comments, and there certainly are many comments that seem to deserve it, **comments are not all that important**: You will notice that old comments, especially those without upvotes on them, don't show up without an additional click when there are upvoted comments present.

Comment: +1, though in my experience mods tend to not investigate flags that are technical inaccuracies/factual errors.

Comment: Very usefull information regarding the status of comments vs regular answers and their lifespan. As a side note, at the time of writing I was not either able to flag the comments...

Comment: They have not implemented an autoflush to my knowledge. Please do as Olin says, do not flag a moderator for technical inaccuracies. Comments are just not that important, answers are the meat, they are discussing autodecay of comments for that reason.

Comment: Flagging is really for things that violate the norms of discourse on the site, not for simple inaccuracies.